# Should one view have one controller in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently working in MVC 5 Web Application and I am being advised to go with one View per Controller approach which I feel will be highly unmaintainable and the advantage of MVC is forfeit.

Kindly suggest as my application will be having around 180 User Interface Pages which would mean 180 Controllers according to the advise.

Comment: Ok, so what's your question?

Comment: You should group your controllers in a logical manner. How that is exactly, is depending on your application.

Comment: If you are *forced* by management / leadership to do this (you can't convince them otherwise), I would definitely use [Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to at least arrange your controllers into logical groups.

Comment: My application has Different Modules So I had developed Module Specific Controller. But now I am being forced to go with One View One Controller for eg. If there are 4 Views Like Contact, Home, Details which are related to one module to have 4 different controllers which i feel is stupidity.

Comment: @ashutoshjambhale: `Like Contact, Home, Details` - that sounds like cases for a controller each, but doesn't e.g. the `Contact` pages have at least 2 views (and actions) like `ContactForm` and `ContactFormSubmitted`?

Comment: Why negatives for the question? I know this is bad question w.r.t basics of MVC but as I am in situation which demands me to do wrong things.

Comment: @ChrFin Yes in that case its correct. To be straight , I have been told not to have more then one ActionResult returning View (except partial views) in controller.

Comment: Do they give you a reason why they would like to have it that way and not the other way?

Comment: @jadarnel27 Yes I will try using Areas. But not sure on convincing as I was not able to w.r.t controllers which is basic understanding.

Comment: @ChrFin was told its the Best Practice and the standard to be followed which cant be questioned.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: **NO**

That's not how `ASP.NET MVC` is meant to work. One controller should "group" all the actions for views which belong to one task/area like a `AccountController` handles all account related actions. How exactly you group them depends on your application.
Of course this does not mean you can not use more than one controller for "account related stuff", but I would only start to split the actions to multiple controllers if the controller is starting to get really big. And with really big I mean several hundret lines of code or higher double digit counts of actions.
But even then it may makes more sense to just move some logic into seperate helper classes and keep all the actions (which may only call a helper method) in one controller.

Imagine the following folder structure for your views:

> -- Views/
>   ---- AccountAction1/
>   ------ AccountAction1.cshtml
>   ---- AccountAction2/
>   ------ AccountAction2.cshtml
>   ---- AccountAction3/
>   ------ AccountAction3.cshtml

Which seems a little strange compared to the following:

> -- Views/
>   ---- Account/
>   ------ Action1.cshtml
>   ------ Action2.cshtml
>   ------ Action3.cshtml